# ODBC connection from WinSrv2008 R2 to WinSrv2022

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to make an ODBC connection from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2022 running SQL server 2019.

I get the following error -

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.2100

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection

TESTS FAILED!

I have tested changing the driver versions but it didnt help
Can you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Looks like port 1433 is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Or possibly TLS 1.2 issues. Have you updated Server 2008 to use TLS 1.2? Speaking of which: it's years out of date now and you should upgrade it.

Comment: It seems like a TLS 1.2 issue - can you point me to resources showing how to upgrade Server 2008 to TLS 1.2 ? . I am upgrading all the old serves to Server 2022 - I need this fix as an intermittent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install this [Update to add support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in Windows Server 2008 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-sp2-windows-embedded-posready-2009-and-windows-embedded-standard-2009-b6ab553a-fa8f-3f5e-287c-e752eb3ce5f4) and ensure you follow the instructions there for the various registry settings.